# Rails Full Text Postgres search: are index in db mandatory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Maybe is a stupid question, but I'm adding full text search to my small CMS.

I'm following the guide [here](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) and I have installed pg_search gem. I add the search function to my Content model and Product mode, and everything is working but is very very slow.

I don't add any index to my db table with migration: I'm searching on content.name and content.summary: do I need indexes too?

Answer (score 1):

No, they aren't mandatory, but they will most likely speed up (significantly) the searches.

From the [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-indexes.html) docs:

> Note that indexes are not mandatory for full text searching, but in cases where a column is searched on a regular basis, an index is usually desirable